# Common C issue I cannot figure out: request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

So I've made a struct to hold information about a Client. I get the compiler error stated as above in the title. I'm still learning pointers so bear with me if I state anything incorrect. From what I'm aware, my typedef has a pointer to an instance of Client. Which means I would need to use -> instead of . for fields of Client. But that didn't work either, I would get the error of `dereferencing to incomplete type`. Any guidance or help would be great!

Client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

typedef struct client_tag *Client;

#endif
```

Client.c

```
#include "client.h"


struct client_tag {
    char id[5];
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
    char phoneNum[15];
};
```

The following file reads client information from a file and assigns them to variables:

```
#include "client.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    Client client1 = malloc(sizeof(Client));
    FILE *fp;
    ListType clientList;

    fp = fopen("clients.txt", "r");

    int lineSize = 200;
    char* line = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line2 = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line3 = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line4 = malloc(lineSize); 


    while (fgets(line, lineSize, fp) != NULL) { 
        strcpy(client1.id, line);
        strcpy(client1.name, fgets(line2, lineSize, fp));
        strcpy(client1.email, fgets(line3, lineSize, fp));
        strcpy(client1.phoneNum, fgets(line4, lineSize, fp));

        push(clientList, (void*)&client1);

        printf("ID: %s", line);
        printf("Name: %s", line2);
        printf("Email: %s", line3);
        printf("Phone Number: %s\n", line4);

        free(line);
        free(line2);
        free(line3);
        free(line4);

        line = malloc(lineSize);
        line2 = malloc(lineSize);
        line3 = malloc(lineSize);
        line4 = malloc(lineSize);

    }

}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    clientDriver.c: In function ‘main’:
clientDriver.c:23:17: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   strcpy(client1.id, line);
                ^
clientDriver.c:24:17: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
   strcpy(client1.name, fgets(line2, lineSize, fp));
                ^
clientDriver.c:25:17: error: request for member ‘email’ in something not a structure or union
   strcpy(client1.email, fgets(line3, lineSize, fp));
                ^
clientDriver.c:26:17: error: request for member ‘phoneNum’ in something not a structure or union
   strcpy(client1.phoneNum, fgets(line4, lineSize, fp));
```

Comment: It's a pointer, use `->` not `.`.

Comment: try &client1->name[0] ... remember the "&" before client1 in strcpy

Comment: Why is `typedef struct client_tag *Client;` in `Client.c` instead of `Client.h`? That typedef isn't applying anywhere but `Client.c` itself.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Like I mentioned, when I do that, I get the `dereferencing to incomplete type` error.

Comment: @user2357112 My apologies, I just labeled my files wrong in this post. I'll edit that now.

Comment: Making your `typedef` a pointer is probably confusing you more; there is no `*` at point of declaration to make it obvious you need to use `->` syntax to access members.

Comment: @morcillo I tried that and I still get the same `request for member....` error

Comment: Since Client is a pointer you are allocating 4 or 8 bytes.  That's probably wrong.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think so too. I just tried to replicate my professor's examples, but my lack of understanding is making this harder.

Comment: Okay, why is your definition of `struct client_tag` in `Client.c` instead of `Client.h`? Actually, why do you have a `Client.c` at all? It doesn't look like any of your code belongs there. You don't have any functions or variables to define there.

Comment: @stark: Good catch. This is part of why I usually favor using `sizeof(*variablename)` instead of `sizeof(type)` for allocation.

Comment: @user2357112 I need to have `client.c` to provide my implementation of what's in the header file.

Comment: @Jasmine: But you don't declare any functions that need implementing.

Comment: The point is, there's nothing in the header file.  That's where your struct definition belongs.

Comment: @user2357112: I'd assume it's for implementation hiding; allows APIs to be defined to take and return `Client` while keeping the structure opaque to API users.

Comment: Hiding a pointer type behind a `typedef` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: If that's the case, then `main` shouldn't be trying to write directly to the underlying fields at all.

Comment: Never `typedef` a pointer!

Comment: @user2357112 I guess that's where my lack of understanding comes in. I've fixed my error and now it runs, thank you!

Comment: @Olaf Since I'm still learning pointers, can you explain why it's bad to typedef a pointer?

Comment: @Jasmine: Please do some research on your own. This has been asked (and answered) a (felt) hundred times already. For a starter: It defies `const`-correctness (or would pollute name-space), and results in confusion on usage. You already fell into this pit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you can't used fields on a `client_tag` or `client_tag *` if you don't have the declaration for `client_tag` in your header file.

My recommendation would be to move the struct declaration for `client_tag` from `client.c` to `client.h`

Based on the above instructions, The following code compiles and runs

## client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

struct client_tag {
    char id[5];
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
    char phoneNum[15];
};

typedef struct client_tag *Client;

#endif
```

## main.c

```
#include "client.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Minimal list implementation
 * Based on functions in your program
 */
typedef struct {
  unsigned length;
  size_t allocated_size;
  void ** items; 
} ListType;

/* Push implemented based on the usage in your code */
int push(ListType l, void* item){
  // check if we need to allocate memory
  if (l.length >= l.allocated_size){
    size_t next_size = (l.allocated_size > 0) ? l.allocated_size * 2 : sizeof(void*);
    l.items = (void **) realloc(l.items, next_size);
    if (l.items == NULL){
      return -1; // error
    }

    l.allocated_size = next_size;
  }

  // push the item;
  l.items[l.length++] = item;
  return l.length;
}

int main() {
    Client client1 = malloc(sizeof(Client));
    FILE *fp;
    ListType clientList;

    fp = fopen("clients.txt", "r");

    int lineSize = 200;
    char* line = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line2 = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line3 = malloc(lineSize);
    char* line4 = malloc(lineSize); 


    while (fgets(line, lineSize, fp) != NULL) { 
        strcpy(client1->id, line);
        strcpy(client1->name, fgets(line2, lineSize, fp));
        strcpy(client1->email, fgets(line3, lineSize, fp));
        strcpy(client1->phoneNum, fgets(line4, lineSize, fp));

        push(clientList, (void*)&client1);

        printf("ID: %s", line);
        printf("Name: %s", line2);
        printf("Email: %s", line3);
        printf("Phone Number: %s\n", line4);

        free(line);
        free(line2);
        free(line3);
        free(line4);

        line = malloc(lineSize);
        line2 = malloc(lineSize);
        line3 = malloc(lineSize);
        line4 = malloc(lineSize);

    }

}
```

## clients.txt

```
1
John Doe
john.doe@example.com
1-555-456-7890
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic answer depends on whether or not you want consumers to treat your custom type as opaque or not. If it does not need to be opaque, use Mobius' advice, and move the full definition to the header.

Otherwise, you'll need to provide functions that return those members, e.g.:

```
char * client_tag_get_name(client_tag *t) {
    return t->name;
}
```

and put the declaration for that in your header.

Comment: So what you're saying is if I keep my structure definition in the c file, that means it'll become a private structure?

Comment: @Jasmine: It means they can't compute the size of the structure or access its members, because they don't have access to the definition. They can pass around the pointer to it, but not allocate their own. Basically everything they do with it would rely on you providing functions that do work for them (with the definition of, but not the declaration of, those functions having access to the structure definition).